# error CS0592: Attribute 'PXForeignReference' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, property, indexer' declarations

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I need to override the InventoryID field on the Purchase Orders screen. I want to make the field a Required field by overriding it on-screen level:

```
namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
  public class POOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    
    
    [PXDefault]
    [POLineInventoryItem(Filterable = true)]
    [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<inventoryID>.IsRelatedTo<InventoryItem.inventoryID>))]
    protected virtual void POLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {
    
    }
    
    #endregion
  }
}
```

When I run the above I get the following error:
\App_RuntimeCode\POOrderEntry.cs(45): error CS0592: Attribute 'PXForeignReference' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, property, indexer' declarations.

Line 45 is  [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field.IsRelatedTo<InventoryItem.inventoryID>))]

How would I go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe foreign reference is "legal" in the context of CacheAttached.  You should be able to use PXMergeAttrubutes to add PXDefault without dropping the other attributes.

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXDefault]
protected virtual void POLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache){}
```

I did something similar to prevent use of a specific Item Class on SOLine.

```
#region SOLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached  
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemClassID,
    NotEqual<Current<MySetup.PreventClassID>>>),"")]
protected virtual void SOLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
#endregion
```

You also might consider PXUIRequiredAttribute if you want to define when it would be required.  I believe this attribute can be used in a DAC Extension or CacheAttached.

```
#region MyDAC_AccountID_CacheAttached
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Current<MyDAC.hold>, Equal<False>,
                        And<Current<MyBranchSetting.requireAccount>, Equal<True>>>))]
protected virtual void MyDAC_AccountID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
#endregion
```